# JPA: How to select by char type column (AttributeConversion included)?

Tags: java, sql, jpa

In my LanguageTrainer application I have got an Entity class ("Article") using an Enum ("Gender") as an attribute "gender" (it represents the gender of the article, so it's only M for male, F for female and so on) which I map to a char(1) column ("gender") in my PostgreSQL database table "article" with an Attribute Converter. If I select the whole dataset with the JPA TypedQuery ("FROM Article a", Article.class) everything is fine, the mapping works. But how do I put the gender into a WHERE clause? (The likes of "FROM Article a WHERE gender='M'") Please enlighten me! When I put the character into single quotes, it tells me "AttributeConverter domain-model attribute type [home_jsp.model.Gender] and JDBC type [java.lang.Character] did not match query literal type [java.lang.String]", without quotes it's "Could not extract result set"/"Column  does not exist" and with double quotes, of course, "Unexpected character"

JPA TypedQuery with which I would like to query my Database (this.em is the EntityManager):

```
List<Article> articles = this.em.createQuery("FROM " + Article.class.getSimpleName() + " a WHERE gender='" + Gender.FEMALE.getCode() + "'", Article.class).getResultList();
```

Enum Gender:

```
public enum Gender {
MALE('M'), 
FEMALE('F'), 
NEUTER('N'), 
UNDEFINED('U');

private final char code;

private Gender(char code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public static Gender fromCode(char code) {
    if (code == 'M') {
        return MALE;
    } else if (code == 'F') {
        return FEMALE;
    } else if (code == 'N') {
        return NEUTER;
    } else if (code == 'U') {
        return UNDEFINED;
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}

public char getCode() {
    return code;
}
}
```

AttributeConverter

```
 @Converter
public class GenderConverter implements AttributeConverter<Gender, Character> {

@Override
public Character convertToDatabaseColumn(Gender gender) {
    if (gender == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return gender.getCode();
}

@Override
public Gender convertToEntityAttribute(Character character) {
    if (character == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return Gender.fromCode(character);
}
}
```

Article class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="\"article\"")
@NamedQuery(name="Article.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Article a")
public class Article implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -4674267116608531826L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

//...other attributes

private String article;

@Convert(converter = home_jsp.model.GenderConverter.class)
private Gender gender;
//... getter and setter
}
```

Comment: Please add on your question the relevant bits of the code. Your enum and your JPA query code. Aside that the issue is likely that you are forcing a "native" like query into a JPA one. When you use `"FROM Article a WHERE gender='M'"` you are not writing a query exactly you are writing something that will be converted into a query given that it matches with the entity. So it should be something like `FROM Article a WHERE a.gender=GenderEnumName.M` (or something along these lines)